# Wrong reasoning for existence solution linear system

Tags: linear-algebra

Let us consider the matrix
$$
A = 
\begin{pmatrix}
&-1 &1 &-1 \\
&-1 &1 &1 \\
&-2 &2 &0
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Let us call $\mathbf c_i\in\mathbb R^3$, $i=1,2,3$, it columns. It holds $\det(A)=0$, entailing there exist $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3\in\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^3 \lambda_i \mathbf c_i=\mathbf 0\in\mathbb R^3$. In particular, we have
$$
\mathbf c_3 = -\frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_3}\mathbf c_1 -\frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_2}\mathbf c_2,
$$
implying the existence of a solution $\mathbf x\in\mathbf R^2$ to the linear system
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\mathbf c_1| \mathbf c_2
\end{pmatrix}
\mathbf x = \mathbf c_3.
$$
Where is the mistake?

Comment: Not all $\lambda_i$ have to be non-zero.

Comment: The general doubt was: does the condition on the determinant of the augmented matrix tells us something about the solvability of the associated linear system? The answer is no, indeed...

Comment: Determinant of the augmented matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that $\lambda_i\neq0$?

Even when vectors $v_1,v_2,v_3$ are linearly dependent, meaning that $\exists c_1,c_2,c_3$, not all $0$, such that $c_1\lambda_1+c_2\lambda_2+c_3\lambda_3=0$, there is a possibility that $c_i=0$ for some $i=1,2,3$.

Comment: Thank you :-)!!